# Is there a way to hide text in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to hide some (but not all) of the text in a TextView?  I tried setting the size to 0 with AbsoluteSizeSpan, but that doesn't have any visual effect that I see.  (You can set the size to 1, and you essentially get bumpy lines instead of readable text.  Cute, but not quite what I'm after.)

By hide, I mean go away, not be visible and not take up space.  Drawing text with the same color as the background isn't what I'm looking for.

I realize I can just replace the text in the TextView with only the text I want to display, but I'm already using spans to do a lot more dynamic styling, and something like a HiddenSpan would be useful.  Does it exist?

Comment: How do you define Hidden in this context? Just visibility?

Comment: Edited to clarify - not displayed, doesn't take up space.

Comment: some context may be useful - is there a reason you don't just setText to what you want the Text to be?

Comment: Sure - imagine that you have a lot of text, with lots of styles applied.  And you want to just temporary hide some characters in the middle, depending on some application context.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for: `TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: This hides the control, but the question is about hiding parts of the text inside the control - they're not the same thing.

Comment: then setText() without the text you want to hide

Answer (score 7):

try by this code:

I have complete by this code..

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvi" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible"
```

or

```
    android:visibility="gone"
/>
```

or by code:-

```
   TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvi);
   txtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

OR

```
  txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

May be this will help you

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="0sp"
  android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Transparent text color hides the visibility of the text.  Add textSize to that to remove or minimize the space it takes up.

Comment: Did you try this and have it work?  When I tried a text size of 0, it left the text as the default size.  A text size of 1 doesn't do it, since it still takes up space even if it's the same color as the background.  (Also, your xml doesn't solve the problem at all, since it applies to all the text in the control, not some of the text.)

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem and wrote the following class:

```
public class NoDisplaySpan extends ReplacementSpan {

    public NoDisplaySpan() {}

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas arg0, CharSequence arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
            float arg4, int arg5, int arg6, int arg7, Paint arg8) {}

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end,
            FontMetricsInt fm) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It seems to only work within a paragraph; I get an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException thrown when I set the span to extend past a newline.  I'd love to hear if anyone can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

just had this issue. Basically you just display a part of the string by using substring or whatever and if you click on the textview, you set the fulltext to it.

Hope it can help out someone going through that topic. (Can copy paste a snipet of code if required).

Comment: This is just a duplicate of @CrackerJack9's comment.  AFAIK, the answer is still "this isn't possible."  (Yes, you can just change the text you're displaying. That's not what the question is about.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer to this, as it is very old, but I found it while looking for something and thought I could help. Have you tried setting one button on the keyboard or a hardware button to switch between the visible TextView and a hidden one. You would have to play around with copying text from visible to hidden if you want to keep the visible as part of the hidden. If you want the hidden to be its own text, then this will be an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way. Let's use SpannableString and Color.TRANSPARENT

For example:
 <> Original text : "Hello dude"

<> Expected text : "_____ dude"

- Here i will use Kotlin:

val spannableString = SpannableString("Hello dude")

spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.TRANSPARENT), 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

yourTextView.text = spannableString

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like that:
https://gist.github.com/RicardAparicio/bdd6cd30410f9431e1da238202a1dfa9

Change some parameters if needed.