# Hide EditText from AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, hide, visibility, invisible

I have created `EditText` via xml file. **I have to hide it when certain condition get true**. I have tried

`setVisibility(View.GONE)`

**and**

`setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

but nothing happens. Is there any specific way to do it or can it be done by another way? Please help me.

Comment: If you post your layout xml and the relevant code (showing obtaining the view and also trying to set its status) someone might be able to help you. Without those details, the quality of any responses you receive will not be very high.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct reference. Also try cleaning the Project (Project -> Clean)

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` has been deprecated for about four years.

Comment: Thanks it working in relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's impossible (well nothing is impossible :-)..check the update!). Check this question [Is there a way to hide text in a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653079/is-there-a-way-to-hide-text-in-a-textview). In an AbsoluteLayout you can only hide the text in a EditText or a TextView, but not the occupied space by these elements. That's why I'd recommend you to use RelativeLayout for this purpose instead of AbsoluteLayout.

**Update**

Using `addView` and `removeView` you can add and delete a View as follows

```
LinearLayout endTimeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.endTimeLayout);
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
if (somecheckbox.isChecked())
   mainLayout.removeView(endTimeLayout);
else
   mainLayout.addView(endTimeLayout);
```

I'd continue recommend you to use RelativeLayouts if it's possible that are easy to manage.

Comment: He needs to hide the View not the Text

Comment: Yes, it's what I said. It's not possible in a absolute layout to hide the View (space occupied) but only the text. That's why I recommend to use relativelayout or check some workarounds in the other stackoverflow question that I have linked. Sorry I have not been clear enough.